# FORTRAN 95: OPTIONAL statement does not work (using FTN95 and Plato)

Tags: fortran, subroutine, option-type, plato

I am having a problem with the `OPTIONAL` statement in functions and subroutines with Fortran 95. Currently I am using Silverfrost's Plato and their FTN95 compiler (in "Release Win32" mode). After trying to implement the OPTIONAL statement in a more complex program I am writing, I created a very simple program to test it. Here is the code:

```
program TEST

implicit none
integer :: a=1, b=2

call Z(a,b)
call Z(a)
call Z(b)

end program TEST

subroutine Z(x,y)
implicit none
integer :: x
integer, optional :: y

if (present(y)) then
  write(*,*) x, y
  else
    write(*,*) x
endif

end subroutine Z
```

I expected the following result displayed on the screen:

```
1 2
1
2
```

Well, the code compiles, although I get a warning (673) that "SUBROUTINE Z has been called with too few arguments". After executing it, I get on my screen:

```
1 2
```

and then an "Access violation" error message. Can somebody understand what is wrong here?

Thanks a lot!
Gilberto

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try putting the subroutine in a module, like so:

```
module testoptional
contains
    subroutine Z(x,y)
    implicit none
    integer :: x
    integer, optional :: y

    if (present(y)) then
      write(*,*) x, y
      else
        write(*,*) x
    endif

    end subroutine Z
end module testoptional

program TEST
    use testoptional
    implicit none
    integer :: a=1, b=2

    call Z(a,b)
    call Z(a)
    call Z(b)

end program TEST
```

Compiling and running then gives the expected result using gfortran and ifort.

The problem is in how the main program knows (or guesses) the interface to `Z(x,y)`.  In the code you provide, although the main program and the subroutine are in the same file, there's nothing explicitly telling the main program the interface - the calling sequence, including argument counts, types, etc - of `Z`.  The first call is to `Z(a,b)`, so it infers there's a subroutine out there somewhere that takes two parameters; then it tries calling it with one parameter, which fails.

Putting the subroutine in a module, then using the module (you could also use `contains` for a contained subroutine, or explicitly/manually providing the main program the interface using an `interface` block) then gives the main program the information it needs about the calling sequence - e.g., that there's an optional argument - and things work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Procedures with optional arguments must have explicit interfaces, so try giving one to `Z`. (E.g. just use the subroutine from a short module.)

I don't have this specific compiler on hand, but I've gotten an error when using the Cray compiler for cases like this.